# CSS: how to remove the top-gap for sub-menus?

Tags: html, css

I've a [code snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/6rh8who4/) of a *vertical fly-out-menu* and would like to **avoid the top gap of the sub-menus**.

I made some progress with `float`, `position` and `top` but got lost in some dirty code.

That's the **desired result**:

[image]

What's a good/best/common practice to solve the problem? Thanks in advance!

```css
/* Define the body style */
body {
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size:12px;
}

/* We remove the margin, padding, and list style of UL and LI components */
#menuwrapper ul, #menuwrapper ul li{
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  list-style:none;
}

/* We apply background color and border bottom white and width to 150px */
#menuwrapper ul li{
  background-color:#7f95db;
  border-bottom:solid 1px white;
  width:150px;
  cursor:pointer;
}

/* We apply the background hover color when user hover the mouse over of the li component */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover{
  background-color:#6679e9;
  position:relative;
}

/* We apply the link style */
#menuwrapper ul li a{
  padding:5px 15px;
  color:#ffffff;
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
}

/**** SECOND LEVEL MENU ****/
/* We make the position to absolute for flyout menu and hidden the ul until the user hover the parent li item */
#menuwrapper ul li ul{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}

/* When user has hovered the li item, we show the ul list by applying display:block, note: 150px is the individual menu width.  */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul{
  left:150px;
  top:0px;
  display:block;
}

/* we apply different background color to 2nd level menu items*/
#menuwrapper ul li ul li{
  background-color:#cae25a;
}

/* We change the background color for the level 2 submenu when hovering the menu */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover{
  background-color:#b1b536;
}

/* We style the color of level 2 links */
#menuwrapper ul li ul li a{
  color:#454444;
  display:inline-block;
  width:120px;
}

/**** THIRD LEVEL MENU ****/
/* We need to hide the 3rd menu, when hovering the first level menu */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li ul{
  position:absolute;
  display:none;
}

/* We show the third level menu only when they hover the second level menu parent */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover ul{
  display:block;
  left:150px;
  top:0;
}

/* We change the background color for the level 3 submenu*/
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li{
  background:#86d3fa;
}

/* We change the background color for the level 3 submenu when hovering the menu */

#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li:hover{
  background:#358ebc;
}

/* We change the level 3 link color */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover ul li:hover ul li a{
  color:#ffffff;
}

/* Clear float */
.clear{
  clear:both;
}
```

```html
<div id="menuwrapper">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Products</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Product 1</a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Product 1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Product 2</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sub Product 3</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Product 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Faqs</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Where are we?</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Help</a>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please provide a minimal and verifyable example in your question

Comment: @TheThirdMan please take a look at the fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/6rh8who4/).

Comment: Aside from the fact that jfiddle doesn't work in my personal browser due to it's settings, a minimal and verifyable example *in your post* will ensure that the content of your post will survive possibly expired links, and will help people in the future to solve similar problems. SO's snippet does whatever jfiddle does for all intents and purposes. Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for more information about this topic

Comment: @TheThirdMan That's a very good point, thanks for reminding.

Comment: @Bassie was faster and added the code. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How does this look:

https://jsfiddle.net/tobyl/um02Loxc/1/

Relevant code:

```
#menuwrapper ul {
  position: relative;
}
```

And:

```
/* We apply the background hover color when user hover the mouse over of the li component */
#menuwrapper ul li:hover{
    background-color:#6679e9;
}
```

Comment: Shame on me. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

say body margin is 0

```
body{
margin:0;
}
```